# How to deploy .so browser plugin on another linux system

Tags: linux, deployment, npapi, firebreath, browser-plugin

I developed a simple linux browser plugin using firebreath framework and it is working fine on my system i.e linux(ubuntu). When I copy the plugin binary (.so file) to another Ubuntu 64/32 bit machine it does not appear to load in the browser plugin list. Tried on these two browsers chrominum and firefox.

How to deploy on another linux system but it's working fine in my system where i build it.

Comment: This is mostly a linux binary deployment question; I don't know the answer myself, but I suspect you'll get more help if you focus more on the fact that it's a linux binary and less on the fact that it's a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in build structure plugin is not able to get required resources. Use Proper Stucture to build your plugin. Read Firebreath Documentation Properly and try to follow in a proper manner. If you not able to understand, please refer to mac documentation, Mac documentation help you to building Linux structure.